# Get first letter of every paragraph from specific div javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the first letter of every paragraph from specific div using javascript or jquery and append that letter into the same paragraph.

Here is my html code:

```
<div id="about-content" class="aboutus-entry-content">
    <p>Maecenas facilisis nec velit Integer lacinia eros vitae risus euismod interdum. Nam ornare cursus nulla, ac pulvinar velit congue eu. Quisque vehicula nulla vel accumsan convallis.</p>
    <p>Curabitur iaculis sodales turpis non feugiat. Praesent scelerisque varius mi eu molestie. Etiam vitae mi augue. Nulla fringilla congue scelerisque. Donec eget pretium leo. Aenean nunc est, elementum</p>

    <p>Nunc eget ullamcorper nunc. Ut ac elit lacus. Sed placerat vestibulum est. Ut nec pulvinar turpis, quis aliquam libero.</p>

</div>
```

Example:

```
<div id="about-content" class="aboutus-entry-content">
    <p>Maecenas facilisis</p>
    <p>ullamcorper nunc</p>
</div>
```

Expected ouput:

```
<div id="about-content" class="aboutus-entry-content">
    <p>
        <div class="first-letter">M</div>
        Maecenas facilisis</p>
    <p>
        <div class="first-letter">u</div>
        ullamcorper nunc</p>
</div>
```

Comment: An example of your expected output would be good.

Comment: `$('#about-content p').each(function() {
  console.log(this.textContent.substr(0, 1));
});`

Comment: @Phylogenesis example added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("p").each(function(index) {
        var textN = $(this).text();
        var firstWord = textN.charAt(0);
        console.log(index + ": " + firstWord);
        $(this).prepend('<div class="first-letter">' + firstWord + '</div>');
        /*$(this).append('<div class="first-letter">'+firstWord+'</div>');*/
    });
});
```

[Demo JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j2g5pgt6/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#about-content > p").each(function(){
  var first_letter = $.trim($(this).text().split(""))[0];
  $(this).append(" "+first_letter)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="about-content" class="aboutus-entry-content">
    <p>Maecenas facilisis nec velit Integer lacinia eros vitae risus euismod interdum. Nam ornare cursus nulla, ac pulvinar velit congue eu. Quisque vehicula nulla vel accumsan convallis.</p>
    <p>Curabitur iaculis sodales turpis non feugiat. Praesent scelerisque varius mi eu molestie. Etiam vitae mi augue. Nulla fringilla congue scelerisque. Donec eget pretium leo. Aenean nunc est, elementum</p>

    <p>Nunc eget ullamcorper nunc. Ut ac elit lacus. Sed placerat vestibulum est. Ut nec pulvinar turpis, quis aliquam libero.</p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the first letter,

```
var firstLetterArray = $("#about-content p").map(function() {
  return $(this).text().trim().charAt(0);
}).get();
```

Answer (score 0):

pure javascript... not sure if works with IE ahaha

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function takeP(){
var d = document.getElementById("about-content");
var allP = d.getElementsByTagName("p");
for(var i = 0;i<allP.length;i++){
console.log(allP[i].innerHTML.substring(0,1));
}
}
</script>   
</head>
<body onload='takeP();'>
<div id="about-content" class="aboutus-entry-content">
    <p>Maecenas facilisis nec velit Integer lacinia eros vitae risus euismod interdum. Nam ornare cursus nulla, ac pulvinar velit congue eu. Quisque vehicula nulla vel accumsan convallis.</p>
    <p>Curabitur iaculis sodales turpis non feugiat. Praesent scelerisque varius mi eu molestie. Etiam vitae mi augue. Nulla fringilla congue scelerisque. Donec eget pretium leo. Aenean nunc est, elementum</p>

    <p>Nunc eget ullamcorper nunc. Ut ac elit lacus. Sed placerat vestibulum est. Ut nec pulvinar turpis, quis aliquam libero.</p>

</div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#about-content p').each(function() { 
  this.textContent=this.textContent+this.textContent.substr(0, 1);
  console.log(this.textContent.substr(0, 1)); });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="about-content" class="aboutus-entry-content">
    <p>Maecenas facilisis nec velit Integer lacinia eros vitae risus euismod interdum. Nam ornare cursus nulla, ac pulvinar velit congue eu. Quisque vehicula nulla vel accumsan convallis.</p>
    <p>Curabitur iaculis sodales turpis non feugiat. Praesent scelerisque varius mi eu molestie. Etiam vitae mi augue. Nulla fringilla congue scelerisque. Donec eget pretium leo. Aenean nunc est, elementum</p>

    <p>Nunc eget ullamcorper nunc. Ut ac elit lacus. Sed placerat vestibulum est. Ut nec pulvinar turpis, quis aliquam libero.</p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `each()` loop and then `prepend()` first letters of each `p`

```js
 $('#about-content p').each(function() {
   $(this).prepend('<div class="first-letter">' + $(this).text().charAt(0) + '</div>')
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="about-content" class="aboutus-entry-content">
  <p>Maecenas facilisis</p>
  <p>ullamcorper nunc</p>
</div>
```